# How can I graph two sensor data values with Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I have some data that I'm graphing with Highcharts, which I was able to set up by using a modified version of some demo code.  The graph works fine when I graph some data from a sensor.  The relevant section of my code looks like this:

```js
<script>
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor:'transparent',
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        y = Number(getTemp());
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        labels: {
            style: {
              },
             },
             tickPixelInterval: 200,
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'linear',
        labels: {
            y: 5,
            style: {
            },
        },
    },

    series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: (function () {
            var data = [],
                time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                i;

            for (i = -200; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                data.push({
                    x: time + i * 1000,
                    y: 0
                });
            }
            return data;
        }())
    }]
});
</script>
```

Now I want to add a second sensor reading using a similar function "getTemp2()" on the same graph as a second series.  When I try to edit the code in the "series" data section, I get a blank graph (meaning it fails to load correctly).  I believe the code in the "series" section populates the graph with zeros (for y values) across the entire chart.  But I'm not sure if I need to add both something in the "events" section, the "series" section, or both?  Can someone tell me how I can add a second sensor reading to this chart?  Here is what I tried that failed:

```js
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        y = Number(getTemp());
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                },
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                        y = Number(getTemp2());
                    series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                }, 1000);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to create two series in a chart configuration object:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {

    ...,

    series: [{
        data: getData()
    }, {
        data: getData()
    }]
});
```

Then, in `load` event you can use `addPoint` method on both of the series:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function() {
            var series1 = this.series[0],
                series2 = this.series[1];

            setInterval(function() {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    y1 = Number(getTemp()),
                    y2 = Number(getTemp2());

                series1.addPoint([x, y1], false, true);
                series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);

            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nk4yawzt/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series